# Javascript Wrong order after Axios subrequest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make a search with Wordpress API, i have no problems to request but during my function my results are not order anymore from the first request. I explain.
My first axios request is a search and it return a list of posts with title and id. But inside a foreach i wanna make a sub request to get a post by id :

```
  methods: {
    getSearch: async function () {
      const query = "/search?subtype=post&search=" + this.$route.query.q;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    getPost: async function (id) {
      const query = "/posts/" + id;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    getCategorie: async function (id) {
      const query = "/categories?post=" + id;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    search: async function () {
      await this.getSearch().then((search) =>
        Promise.all(search).then(
          search.forEach(async (tuto) => {
            console.log(tuto.title); // Result in order
            await this.getPost(tuto.id).then((post) => {
              console.log(post.title); // Not the same order
            });
          })
        )
      );

      console.log(this.tutos_search);
    },
  },
```

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with async/await but i can't find a solution.

This is the console :

```
487
493
480
463
458
Proxy {}[[Handler]]: Object[[Target]]: Array(0)[[IsRevoked]]: false
480
487
458
493
463
```

As you can see, it's not the same order between first log and second, and in the middle we see my last console.log. Don't understand why because i have await.

FYI i use VueJS. Thanks a lot

Comment: Asynchronous tasks are not guaranteed to be finished in the same order they were called.

Comment: Be aware that forEach will not wait even if you use async/await, if you really need to, use a for loop instead.

Comment: Mixing `async`/`await` with `.then()` is usually discouraged. Little reason to use `.then()` (instead of `await`) when you're in an `async` function. Also the `Promise.all(search)` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, since `search` is the result of your API call and is not an array of Promises.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I am not 100% satisfied but my code below work !!

```
  methods: {
    getSearch: async function () {
      const query = "/search?subtype=post&search=" + this.$route.query.q;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    getPost: async function (id) {
      const query = "/posts/" + id;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    getCategorie: async function (id) {
      const query = "/categories?post=" + id;
      const response = await this.axios.get(query);
      return response.data;
    },
    search: async function () {
      const search = await this.getSearch();

      for (let i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
        const id = search[i].id;
        const post = await this.getPost(id);
        const categories = await this.getCategorie(id);
        post.categories.length = 0;
        post.categories = categories;
        console.log(post);
      }
    },
  },
```